# Memory Leaks in C# WPF

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, profiling

I could use some advice on tracking down the cause of memory leaks in C#. I understand what is a memory leak and I get why they occur in C# but I'm wondering what tools/strategies have you used in the past to resolve them?

I am using .NET Memory Profiler and I've found that one of my huge main objects is staying in memory after I close the window it manages but I'm not sure what to do to severe all links to it.

If I'm not being clear enough just post an answer with a question and I'll edit my question in response. Thanks!

Comment: also try the Ants Memory Profiler, as it will show witch objects points to a given object

Answer (score 39):

Break into the debugger and then type this into the Immediate window:

```
.load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\sos.dll
```

The path to sos.dll varies. The way to find out the correct path is to look for mscorwks.dll in the Modules pane. Wherever that is loaded from is the correct path for sos.dll.

Then type this:

```
System.GC.Collect()
```

That will ensure anything not reachable is collected. Then type this:

```
!DumpHeap -type <some-type-name>
```

This will show you a table of all existing instances, with addresses. You can find out what is keeping an instance alive like this:

```
!gcroot <some-address>
```

Comment: I had to use System.GC.Collect() to get garbage collection to work.

Comment: I think that may depend on where the debugger has stopped when you break into it. I'll fix my answer so it works regardless.

Answer (score 9):

.NET Memory Profiler is an excellent tool, and one that I use frequently to diagnose memory leaks in WPF applications.

As I'm sure you're aware, a good way to use it is to take a snapshot before using a particular feature, then take a second snapshot after using it, closing the window, etc. When comparing the two snapshots, you can see how many objects of a certain type are being allocated but not freed: this is a leak.

After double-clicking on a type, the profiler will show you the shortest root paths keeping objects of that type alive. There are many different ways that .NET objects can leak in WPF, so posting the root path that you are seeing should help identify the ultimate cause. In general, however, try to understand why those objects are holding onto your object, and see if there's some way you can detach your event handlers, bindings, etc. when the window is closed.

I recently posted a [blog entry](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/10/detecting_bindings_that_should_be_onetime.html) about a particular [memory leak](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416) that can be caused by certain bindings; for that specific types of leak, the code there is useful for finding the Binding that's at fault.