# Trouble with allocating new memory for array in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

Ok I'm having a hard time understanding what I'm doing wrong. In my header file, I have a pointer to an array of pointers to images:

```
Image **images;
int maximum; //size
```

This is part of a class called scene. Now, scene has a member function called changemax, which changes the size of the images array. You can decrease or increase.

And so what I've done was set up a temporary array called `newArray`, copy all the values from `this->images`, delete `this->images`, then allocate new memory for `images`, copy from `newArray` to `images`, and then delete `newArray`.

I get over 100,000 errors with Valgrind, although the code does compile. In specific, I dont think Valgrind likes the line that says `images=new Image*[newmax];`

Comment: Any specific reason you are not using a container class?

Comment: @Jim what do you mean by container class?

Comment: `std::vector`, for example. [If you have to use `delete`, you're doing it wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963610/visual-c-native-memory-management-best-practices).

Comment: Hmm dont know what that is. But this is the way we're supposed to do it.

Comment: It's obvious that you are extremely confused about what you're doing. Half your function isn't even necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly have a memory leak here:

```
newArray[i]=new Image;
if(images[i] !=NULL) {
    // ...
}
else {
    newArray[i]=NULL;
}
```

Why are you creating *two* new arrays?  You only need to create one new array, copy the contents of the old array into the new array, destroy the old array, and then assign `images` to point to the new array.

Why are you creating new `Image` objects?  Since you are only changing the size of the `images` array, you can simply move all of the pointers that you have into the new array without creating any new `Image` objects.

As I said in the comments, you should absolutely be using a `std::vector` or some other sequence container from the C++ Standard Library for this, for example a `std::vector<Image>`.  The requirements are poor and I would strongly recommend a design change.

Comment: By two new arrays, you mean `newArray` is unnecessary? What confuses me is that if I did without `newArray`, then how would I copy from images to images if they have the same name?

Comment: @mohabitar:  You create two new arrays:  `Image **newArray = new Image*[newmax];` ... `images=new Image*[newmax];`  You just need to assign `images = newimages;`.

Comment: Ok so I've changed it to say images=newArray; Then I made a for loop and copied all the individual pointers (even without the for loop step I get the same errors). But I still get infinite errors from Valgrind. Dont the pointers to newArray go out of scope after the function completes?

Comment: Maybe I should have bolded this statement: **The requirements are poor and I would strongly recommend a design change.**

Answer (score 1):

This whole section of code is dead wrong and can be replaced by exactly one line that is correct:

```
images=new Image*[newmax];
for (int i=0;i<newmax;i++){
    if (newArray[i]!=NULL) {
        images[i]=new Image;
        *images[i]=*newArray[i];
    }
    else {
        images[i]=NULL;
    }

    delete newArray[i];
}
delete [] newArray;
```

and nothing even resembling that line appears in the code. Well, OK, the first line is vaguely similar, but only vaguely.

Comment: So I guess youre hinting at what James has above?

Comment: @mohabitar - Yes, I was. I didn't want to say it exactly because this is homework, and you should figure it out for yourself. And, BTW, everybody telling you that this is a really dumb way to do it and that you should be using `::std::vector` is correct. I really hate when schools teach the 'wrong' way to do something because they can't think of any better way to teach the material. Here you're supposed to be learning about memory allocation, arrays and pointers.