# error: no matching function for call to > ‘std::vector<MemberListEntry>::push_back and

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Hi I am trying to insert an object of type MemberListEntry into a vector memberList containing the type . For this I am trying to use push_back function of vector, but it is giving me an error.

```
MemberListEntry *object = new MemberListEntry(id, port, memberNode->heartbeat, par->getcurrtime());
memberNode->memberList.push_back(object);
```

> MP1Node.cpp:118:41: error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘std::vector::push_back(MemberListEntry*&)’
>   memberNode->memberList.push_back(object);

This is my vector

```
vector<MemberListEntry> memberList;
```

in class

> class Member {.........

on changing to

```
memberNode->memberList.push_back<MemberListEntry>(object);
```

gives

> error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
>   memberNode->memberList.push_back(object);

Comment: Just for the case that you have a background in Java, PHP, C#, don't use `new` in C++ like you would use it in those languages!

Comment: Thank you for your comment @UlrichEckhardt ...can you explain me how are the objects being created or Constructor being called in the answers below. I only know that constructor is called upon creation with 'new' keyword.

Comment: Actually, that explanation would be kind-of lengthy. However, knowing that not only `new` creates objects, you should now see plenty of examples in any tutorial or text about C++, where objects are created without `new`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put a pointer into a vector that does not contain pointers. You have two possibility:

1- Change your `vector<MemberListEntry>` to `vector<MemberListEntry*>`

2- Change your first line to:

```
MemberListEntry object(id, port, memberNode->heartbeat, par->getcurrtime());
```

If you use the first one, make sure to call delete on the elements of the vector.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, the second one worked, the first I cannot do because I am not allowed to change the file in which the code resides.

Can you please explain me how did it worked, I only studied that Constructor gets called on object creation and we create object with the use of 'new' operator. Sorry for limited knowledge.

OBLIGED!

Comment: This actually sound like you are lacking some basic knowledge of C++ and you should read on it. You only use new on pointers, indicated by the *. The constructor gets called everytime an object is constructed, pointer or not. Most of the time, you don't want to to use pointer unless really needed. Like I said, I suggest you go read on C++ as it is basic C++ knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

`memberList` contains `MemberListEntry`s and not `MemberListEntry *`s. Why do you want to dynamically allocate the `MemberListEntry`? Replace

```
MemberListEntry *object = new MemberListEntry(id, port, memberNode->heartbeat, par->getcurrtime());
memberNode->memberList.push_back(object);
```

with

```
memberNode->memberList.push_back(MemberListEntry(id, port, memberNode->heartbeat, par->getcurrtime()));
```

or better yet

```
memberNode->memberList.emplace_back(id, port, memberNode->heartbeat, par->getcurrtime());
```

Comment: Hi, yes it works @Praetorian , but how does it works, the memberList is a vector of type MemberListEntry, then how do we place all this stuff directly, are we allowed to simply put it there? 

and in the first code MemberListEntry is a class so how does the constructor gets called without using new keyword?? 

Please explain....

Thank you so much for your help :) :)

Comment: @Bhavya Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6500313/241631), it explains why dynamic allocation should not be the preferred approach in C++. But your question really indicates you should be reading [a book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/241631) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this problem by simply deleting `*` and `new` from your first line.

This may be less efficient under some circumstance when compared to the other (also correct) suggestions, but it is a simpler change, and absolute maximum performance will rarely make a difference for this sort of thing.

I would like to point you to an earlier post of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1701455/86967) for a little bit of background on the use of `new` in C++.  To summarize that post, in C++ you don't call `new` to create an object, you just call the constructor.  The use of `new` only changes how the memory is allocated for the object.  Without `new`, the memory is allocated and managed automatically, but with `new` it is managed dynamically (using a [heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308751/what-is-a-memory-heap)) and must be handled a bit more carefully by the programmer.

Comment: Thanks. I got it, I hope so :)