# Proper Object Disposal In C++/CLI

Tags: garbage-collection, c++-cli, destructor, idisposable, delete-operator

Consider the following class:

```cpp
public ref class Workspace
{
protected:
    Form^                 WorkspaceUI;
    SplitContainer^       WorkspaceSplitter;
    AvalonEditTextEditor^ TextEditor;
    ScriptOffsetViewer^   OffsetViewer;
    SimpleTextViewer^     PreprocessedTextViewer;

    ListView^             MessageList;
    ListView^             FindList;
    ListView^             BookmarkList;
    ListView^             VariableIndexList;
    TextBox^              VariableIndexEditBox;
    Label^                SpoilerText;

    ToolStrip^            WorkspaceMainToolBar;
    ToolStripButton^      ToolBarNewScript;
    ToolStripButton^      ToolBarOpenScript;
    ToolStripButton^      ToolBarPreviousScript;
    ToolStripButton^      ToolBarNextScript;
    ToolStripSplitButton^ ToolBarSaveScript;
    ToolStripDropDown^    ToolBarSaveScriptDropDown;
    ToolStripButton^      ToolBarSaveScriptNoCompile;
    ToolStripButton^      ToolBarSaveScriptAndPlugin;
    ToolStripButton^      ToolBarRecompileScripts;
    ToolStripButton^      ToolBarCompileDependencies;
    ToolStripButton^      ToolBarDeleteScript;
    ToolStripButton^      ToolBarNavigationBack;
    ToolStripButton^      ToolBarNavigationForward;
    ToolStripButton^      ToolBarSaveAll;
    ToolStripButton^      ToolBarOptions;

    ArbitraryCustomClass^ CustomClassInstance;

public:
    Workspace()
    {
        WorkspaceUI = gcnew Form();
        WorkspaceSplitter = gcnew SplitContainer();
        // ...
        Form->Controls->Add(WorkspaceSplitter);
        // ...

        WorkspaceUI->Show();
    }

    ~Workspace
    {
        // dispose stuff here
    }
};
```

What would be the most efficient and elegant way to dispose an instance of the above class so that all of its memory is reclaimed by the GC during its next collection? Do I need to call *delete* explicitly on each member and/or reset them to *nullptr*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NB.** You may not need to do anything. Memory for objects is reclaimed by the GC when references no longer exist that point to it.

You only need to explicitly reclaim when an object implements `IDisposable`. In C++/CLI this maps to destructors.

So if none of the objects you're allocating need to be disposed, you can ignore the rest of this answer. But supposing they do...

Remove the `^` from each field and they will be reclaimed automatically.

It would also mean that they would be default-constructed automatically when the `Workspace` is constructed, which may save you a lot of `gcnew` stuff in your hand-written constructor.

That is, if you say:

```
Form WorkspaceUI;
```

Then you don't need to say:

```
WorkspaceUI = gcnew Form();
```

The compiler has already generated that for you - imagine it being inserted at the start of your constructor.

Nor do you need to dispose/delete anything.

Finally, you need to use `.` instead of `->` to access members of the objects that you declare in this way:

```
Form.Controls->Add(WorkspaceSplitter);
```

**Update:**

In C++/CLI, handles to ref classes are declared with `^`, and this is analogous to the way pointers to native classes are declared with `*`.

Also correspondingly, there needs to be a way to get a handle to an object. To get a pointer to a native object, we prefix with `&`. To get a handle to a ref object, we prefix with `%`. For example:

```
ref class Fred { };

// function that accepts a handle
void ping(Fred ^h) { }

// Elsewhere... declare object of type Fred
Fred f;

// Get handle to pass to function
ping(%f);
```

If repeatedly creating and deleting objects of your class leads to out-of-memory there are two possibilities:

- You are inadvertently holding references to it (or something it allocates). See my answer to this question: [Memory Leaks in C# WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227909/memory-leaks-in-c-sharp-wpf/227966#227966) (it doesn't have anything specific to do with C# or WPF really, it's just a matter of using the debugger interactively)
- You need to call `Dispose` on one or more of the objects you allocate inside your class.

If it's the latter, in C++/CLI there is built-in support for calling `Dispose` automatically - C++/CLI treats a disposable object as if it was a C++ ref class with a destructor.

So if you delete a handle, you're calling `Dispose` on the object it points to.

Or if (as I suggest above) you simply have member objects, you don't even need to explicitly delete. When the outer containing class is destructed (i.e. something calls its `Dispose` method), it will automatically call `Dispose` on any member objects that require it.

Comment: In that case, how will pass the objects to functions that require their handles? As in:
Label SomeText;
Form.Controls->Add(SomeText);  // raises a compiler error

Comment: Also, continued creation and destruction of the above class only leads to the System.OutOfMemoryException - The GC doesn't seem to be reclaiming the memory of the object. This leads me to believe that it might have strong references to even past destruction. In my code, all of the class's instances are allocated and added directly to a list. When destroyed, the instances is removed from the same. That is the only reference each instance gets in the root. There are however multiple inner-references made by the various members of the class.

Comment: @shadeMe: You need to call `Dispose` on the `Workspace` object itself, to trigger disposal of all owned objects.

Comment: There is never a Dispose method in C++/CLI. The compiler will not allow one to be explicitly declared, and if you try to call Dispose on an object the compiler denies that one exists. The correct thing to do is either use `delete h` where `h` is the handle to the object (which I assume is what @shadeMe means by "destroy") or to declare an object (not a handle) so it is automatically destroyed when it leaves scope or the enclosing object destructs.